# Backstage Custom Action to Append file

Tags: typescript, custom-action, backstage

thank's in advance.

I want to append a file after fetching files using fetch:template Action

example:-
below is my fetch action

```
steps:
    - id: fetch provisioning template
      name: fetch provisioning template
      action: fetch:template
      input:
        targetPath: folder
        url: https://github.com/rmccue/test-repository
```

After fetching I want append some content in fetched file, example opml.php.
I am very new to typescript. Is there a action available which i can use to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Check out the scaffolder-backend-module-utils package of custom Backstage actions which includes an action for appending to a file, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@roadiehq/scaffolder-backend-module-utils#append.